# App Engine Backend not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having a hard time getting a backend to run on the GAE servers.  The following works locally, but not when deployed:

counter.py:

```
from google.appengine.api import logservice
logservice.AUTOFLUSH_ENABLED = False
logging.error("Backend started!")
logservice.flush()
```

No log message is seen when deployed.  I've even tried putting syntax error's in, they are not reported either, so it doesn't seem like the backend is actually running my code.  I've tried doing the same in infinite loops with sleeps and such too, same result.

Here is the backends.yaml:

```
backends:
- name: counter
  start: counter.py
  instances: 1
  class: B1
```

The backend is listed as running in the management console, but doesn't seem to be actually doing anything.

Anyone able to get a backend running on the GAE servers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to call a backend service: scheduled Backend, tasked Backend and browsed Backend. Try `http://counter.appname.appspot.com/path`.

Sources:

- http://www.pdjamez.com/2011/05/google-app-engine-backend-patterns/
- http://www.pdjamez.com/2011/05/google-app-engine-backends/comment-page-1/

Comment: I'll check those out.  This is a resident Backend though, I thought if it was given a start parameter, that script would be called automatically when the Backend starts.

Comment: Aha, the answer was in there... it was working all along.  I just couldn't see it:  "To see the results of your backend run, you need to be sure to change to the backend view. To do this go to the drop down at the top of the admin console and change from the current version to the named backend. "